# Unable to change resolution after ubuntu.css edit (18.04)

Tags: 18.04, display-resolution, css

I made a very silly mistake of editing my ubuntu.css file (`/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css`) without making a backup in the process of attempting to change the screen-lock/login wallpaper (https://vitux.com/8-ways-to-customize-your-ubuntu-desktop/).

I only made the suggested changes to the #lockDialogGroup, and rebooted, but now am forced to used a 640x480 resolution, and cant seem to change it (the Resolution Settings panel doesn't allow me to select *any* resolution).

Is there any way around this?

Comment: FWIW, I changed everything back to what it was before in the ubuntu.css file, and the resolution change is persisting.

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to re-install NVIDIA drivers to no avail, and also tried to reset to default theme/icons, which didn't help. I had to run a master `sudo apt-get update`, which fixed everything!